# Grayscale image as input to keras model

Tags: conv-neural-network

For building a CNN in keras Sequential model, we put

```
input_shape = 224*224*3
```

generally for RGB image. Should I put 224*224*1 for gray scale image? What should I do for gray scale image?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert RGB images to grayscale. After that, "Yes" your input should look something like:

```
input_shape = 224*224*1
```